# Creating a bridge to a password-protected destination with WLST

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I'm trying to setup a bridge using wlst.sh with JPython. I managed to create bridge local destination. But when I tried to create bridge remote destination where I need to set password, I got:

```
weblogic.security.internal.SerializedSystemIniException: [Security:090207]Version mismatch. have 2, expected 1
        at weblogic.security.internal.SerializedSystemIni.<init>(SerializedSystemIni.java:127)
        at weblogic.security.internal.SerializedSystemIni.getEncryptionService(SerializedSystemIni.java:260)
        at weblogic.management.scripting.EditHandler.encrypt(EditHandler.java:1026)
        at weblogic.management.scripting.WLScriptContext.encrypt(WLScriptContext.java:850)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

How I did it? Please see the following snippet:

```
wl.cd('/JMSBridgeDestinations/' + bridge_destination_name)
wl.set('ConnectionURL', connection_url)
wl.set('UserName', username)
password = wl.encrypt('hello', '/wls_domains/mywls')    # This line failed to run
wl.set('UserPassword', password)
```

So, it is the encryption that failed.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you try wl.set('UserPasswordEncrypted', password) instead of wl.set('UserPassword', password)

Comment: It's the encryption which failed. Sorry.

Comment: Version of weblogic ?
Are you working online or offline inside your script ?

Comment: I'm using Weblogic 10.3.0.0. I'm using `./wlst.sh myscript.py`

Comment: inside your script, do you connect to the admin server before running commands ?

Comment: Yes. I connect to the server I want to manage the resources.